# How to match string from collection A with collection B in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have collection A as

```
-> {"_id": .... , "data":"demon"}
-> {"_id": .... , "data":"god"}
```

collection B as

```
-> {"_id": .... , "title": "Book A", "description": "this book is about a demon."}
-> {"_id": .... , "title": "Book B", "description": "this book is about a god from Greek."}
-> {"_id": .... , "title": "Book C", "description": "this book is about a dog."}
```

I want to extract documents from collection B where description does not contain any text from collection A's "data" field.

in Plain JS, I want the following in Mongo Query

```
collectionA.filter( x => { return !collectionB.some(y => x.description.includes(y.data)});
```

How can I achieve this in MongoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this would get the desired result i think but don't know how efficient it would be with a lot of data.

```java
db.A.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            data: 1
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup:
        {
            from: 'B',
            let: { word: '$data' },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $regexMatch: {
                                input: '$description',
                                regex: '$$word'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $project: { _id: 1 }
                }
            ],
            as: 'found'
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            ids: {
                $addToSet: {
                    $arrayElemAt: ['$found', 0]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $set: {
            ids: {
                $map: {
                    input: '$ids',
                    in: '$$this._id'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'B',
            let: { found_ids: '$ids' },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $not: {
                                $in: ['$_id', '$$found_ids']
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: 'docs'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$docs'
    },
    {
        $replaceWith: '$docs'
    }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/YMrYeiUOQdo